# Graph API Page Mentions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

How can I retrieve Page mentions made by user in their own wall (both comments & posts).
When I query the Page's feed those mentions aren't retrieved and I cannot find Page's edges that can retrieve those posts/comments

Comment: These mentions are only available on the `/page-ID/feed` edge if the user's privacy settings allow the page management app to see these posts. User's posts that are on the page's timeline directly will be retrievable by page management apps.

Comment: those privacy settings are to specific pages or to all the pages?

Comment: Both; users can block specific pages, and they can block specific - or all - apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API call gets you all the public mentions of your page: `{page_id}/tagged`.